# Vaadin ListSelect in mobile browser - Change "X selected" text

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have ListSelect component in vaadin application. Component is set to multi select mode. When using mobile browser and selecting items (more than one), the component shows text "X selected" where X is the number of selected items.

Can I change that "X selected" text somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The ListSelect component uses `<select>` tag behind the scenes, and devices use their own native OS level components to represent that. If you really need to change that behaviour, you should implement the client side counter part for that component with raw div elements, CSS and client side code (GWT/Java or JS).